# update a table on my website

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Hey all and thank you in advance for any help, I have my website I'm building as a hobby I have an java app I wrote sitting on my comp, it updates certain tables and the the end result is a table shown to users, now I update the tables manually using phpmyadmin.

The question is how do I set a connection to import tables into my website DB?

I googled it before I asked, haven't found related stuff....

Comment: Use a server side language like PHP. Google `$mysqli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want (dozens in fact). One way, that I personally use is through `PHP` and the `$mysqli` class.

[Read more on mysqli here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

You will need to setup a database conection, and from here you would use this connection to query your database by building `SQL` queries and using the `$mysqli` class to send them to the database.

Comment: The problem is not how to interact with the DB but rather how to update my host DB after my local one is finished updating.

Comment: @Raeldrouianov Can you explain further?

Comment: Sure, I have a db on sitting on my computer, I exported some table out of it manually and uploaded them to a website(which I assume is in a different location), now I want to do this action automatically every time I finish updating the tables on my computer...

Comment: Sure, so you would just do this:

1. Connect to local database
2. Query local database
3. Connect to database on external website
4. User an `insert` query to insert the data to the website

Comment: @Raeldrouianov If my answer is not helping you please let me know and I'll just delete it.

Comment: It did. Sorry for not responding earlier.